# Function doesn't print all my vector elements

Tags: c, arrays, vector

I have this vector:

```
int vec[7]={32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 0};
```

and this function:

```
void print(int v[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
        printf("%d", v[i]);
}
```

but I don't understand why it doesn't print the `0` at the end. Why? How can I fix the issue?

Comment: The `vec` array size is 7.

Comment: @aristotll yes, I can see 7 elements. But see the loop: `for(i=0;i<6;i++)`. It starts counting from 0 so it should count the `0` too since `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6` are 7 elements.

Comment: But it stops at 5...

Comment: @aristotll I don't understand. It should print `v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3], v[4], v[5], v[6]`, so why should it stop?

Comment: Vector size is not 6. It will be 7

Comment: `i < 6` means `i` **less than** `6`, not "less than or equal to" . So `v[6]` won't happen

Answer (score 5):

You should change your for loop to:

```
 for(i=0;i<7;i++)
```

or to:

```
for(i=0;i<=6;i++)
```

Answer (score 2):

Working code is http://rextester.com/LBLJPN72634

```
#include  <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int vec[7]={32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 0};

    print(vec);
    return 0;
}

void print(int v[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
        printf("%d\n", v[i]);
}
```